# How to clear DrawableAnimation?

Tags: java, android, animation

**EDIT: CODE NOW FIXED**

I'm trying to create a dynamically populated frame animation for a simple slot reel. I create a random sequence of 50 animated images to make it look like the reel is spinning, then add the final three symbols at the end.

My problem is that each time this method is run, it adds the frames onto the previous Animation. The first time it is run, the animation has 53 frames, the second time it has 106 frames, etc. I want to  reset/clear the animation each time it is run, but I cannot figure out how to do so. If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated!

```
  private void animate(int r1c1, int r2c1, int r3c1, int r1c2, int r2c2, int r3c2, int r1c3, int r2c3, int r3c3) {
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.animationImage);
    imgView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();


    BitmapDrawable cherry = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cherry);
    BitmapDrawable grape = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.grape);
    BitmapDrawable lemon = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lemon);
    BitmapDrawable lucky7 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lucky7);
    BitmapDrawable watermelon = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.watermelon);
    BitmapDrawable orange = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.orange);
    BitmapDrawable[] symbols = {cherry,watermelon,grape,lemon,orange,lucky7};
   // frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imgView.getBackground();
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        frameAnimation.addFrame(symbols[(int)(Math.random() * 6)], 50);

    }
    frameAnimation.addFrame(symbols[r3c1], 200);
    frameAnimation.addFrame(symbols[r2c1], 200);
    frameAnimation.addFrame(symbols[r1c1], 200);
    imgView.setBackgroundDrawable(frameAnimation);

    if (frameAnimation.isRunning()) {
        frameAnimation.stop();
        frameAnimation.selectDrawable(0);
        frameAnimation.start();
    }
    else {

        frameAnimation.start();
    }


}
```

Here is my frameanimation.xml file

```
<animation-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="true">

</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear the animation from any view you can use `view.clearAnimation()`

Provide your complete code for more clearification.

Comment: I've added my xml file if that helps. The java code I've pasted is the entire complete code for that method. The method is simply called when a button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: Reset its drawable resource and restart animation.

```
if (frameAnimation.isRunning()) {
    frameAnimation.stop();
    imgView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frame_animation);
    frameAnimation.start();
}
```

Or you can use [selectDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/DrawableContainer.html#selectDrawable%28int%29):

```
if (frameAnimation.isRunning()) {
    frameAnimation.stop();
    frameAnimation.selectDrawable(0);
    frameAnimation.start();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm neither seem to work. They both just add the frames on and run the larger animation. I've added my animation xml file too if that helps

Comment: Is the problem that I'm using an animation xml file in the first place?